# Migrating MDB JMS queues from Websphere to WebLogic 12C

Tags: java, ejb, jms, weblogic

I am in the process of migrating MDB JMS queues from Websphere to WebLogic server. When I deploy the EAR file in WL, I am getting the below exception.

> weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentException: [J2EE:160238]The message-
>   destination jms/sizeProfileITSARequestQueue declared in the deployment
>   descriptor or by annotation does not have a corresponding message-destination-
>   descriptor element in the weblogic deployment descriptor

I have defined all the neccessary information in Ejb-jar.xml file as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar id="ejb-jar_ID" version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd">
    <display-name>ESo-Listeners</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <message-driven id="PDBListenerBean">
            <ejb-name>PDBListener</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.*.ejb.PDBSizeProfileBean</ejb-class>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>
            <message-destination-link>jms/sizeProfilePDBRequestQueue</message-destination-link>


            <env-entry>
                <description></description>
                <env-entry-name>ejb/BeanFactoryPath</env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value>context/eso-application-config.xml</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>


            <resource-ref>
                <res-ref-name>jdbc/ESODS</res-ref-name>
                <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
                <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
                <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>

            </resource-ref>

            <resource-ref>
                <res-ref-name>jdbc/ESOLOGDS</res-ref-name>
                <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
                <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
                <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>

            </resource-ref>
        </message-driven>
        <message-driven id="ITSAListenerBean">
            <ejb-name>ITSAListener</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.*.ejb.ITSASizeProfileBean</ejb-class>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>
            <message-destination-link>jms/sizeProfileITSARequestQueue</message-destination-link>


            <env-entry>
                <description></description>
                <env-entry-name>ejb/BeanFactoryPath</env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value>context/eso-application-config.xml</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>


            <resource-ref>
                <res-ref-name>jdbc/ESODS</res-ref-name>
                <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
                <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
                <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>

            </resource-ref>
            <resource-ref>
                <res-ref-name>jdbc/ESOLOGDS</res-ref-name>
                <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
                <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
                <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>

            </resource-ref>


        </message-driven>
        <message-driven id="PIListenerBean">
            <ejb-name>PIListener</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.*.ejb.PlanImportBean</ejb-class>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>
            <message-destination-link>jms/planImportRequestQueue</message-destination-link>

            <env-entry>
                <description></description>
                <env-entry-name>ejb/BeanFactoryPath</env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value>context/eso-application-config.xml</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>    

            <resource-ref>
                <res-ref-name>jdbc/ESODS</res-ref-name>
                <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
                <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
                <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>

            </resource-ref> 
            <resource-ref>
                <res-ref-name>jdbc/ESOLOGDS</res-ref-name>
                <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
                <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
                <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>

            </resource-ref>
        </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>
    <assembly-descriptor id="AssemblyDescriptor_1287573859084">
        <message-destination>
            <message-destination-name>jms/sizeProfileITSARequestQueue</message-destination-name>
        </message-destination>
        <message-destination>
            <message-destination-name>jms/sizeProfilePDBRequestQueue</message-destination-name>
        </message-destination>
        <message-destination>
            <message-destination-name>jms/planImportRequestQueue</message-destination-name>
        </message-destination>
        <container-transaction>
            <method>
                <ejb-name>PDBListener</ejb-name>
                <method-name>onMessage</method-name>
                <method-params>
                    <method-param>javax.jms.Message</method-param>
                </method-params>
            </method>
            <method>
                <ejb-name>ITSAListener</ejb-name>
                <method-name>onMessage</method-name>
                <method-params>
                    <method-param>javax.jms.Message</method-param>
                </method-params>
            </method>
            <method>
                <ejb-name>PIListener</ejb-name>
                <method-name>onMessage</method-name>
                <method-params>
                    <method-param>javax.jms.Message</method-param>
                </method-params>
            </method>   
            <trans-attribute>Supports</trans-attribute>
        </container-transaction>
    </assembly-descriptor>

</ejb-jar>
```

Comment: Also should I declare weblogic-ejb-jar.xml in the application? which path should I mention?

Comment: Problem is solved by defining all the JMS queue information in weblogic-ejb-jar.xml file.